# Read some lines without blocking

Tags: java, smtp, java.util.scanner

I'm working in a SMTP client, in which i have defined a SSLSocket and a Scanner related to the inputStream of that socket.
The case is:
If i use HELO command, any problem appears, but if i use EHLO, the problem appears when i try to read all the commands inputStream. The program is still running but it expects something from the inputStream that is not going to arrive. I thought that a good strategy was to use hasNextLine().

```
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
                .createSocket(InetAddress.getByName(address), port);
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {
            respuesta = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("S: " + respuesta);
        }
```

So what i'm trying to do is to read all the messages the server is sending like pipelining, auth login plain, help... before i send AUTH LOGIN, in order to make more clear the program. I've tried to use a while with a int var like:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 8) {
        respuesta = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("S: " + respuesta);
        i++;
}
```

But i founded that in some SMTPservers instead of sending 8 messages, they send 7, so that strategy doesn't work for all the SMTP servers

Comment: Why don't you want to use [java-mail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/)?

Comment: Recently i've studying mail protocols and http in my degree, so a way for me, to study it well is to develop by myself programs like this. But i guess that when i learn properly how that protocols work i'll be using java-mail for example

Comment: Well, you may use [Selector](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector) or put the reading code into a separate thread with the proper [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: I'll try. But the goal is to control when i have something to read from the inputStream(ex: 250 pipelinig) to continue the execution

Comment: I think a protocol specification should tell you that - which response line means that everything is ok and you may continue, and you just go ahead, letting the separate reader thread consume the rest. Most of times it is a bad idea to assume and rely on certain amount of data to be consumed. If you aren't tied to Java try to do this with Node.js, maybe async approach will fit better.